# Export-PfxCertificate Not Protecting Private Key

Tags: powershell, ssl, x509certificate

I am trying to export a certificate public and private key to a PFX file via a powershell script.  I am currently using the following code

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$Thumbprint | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath $OutputFile -Password $privateKeyPass -ChainOption EndEntityCertOnly
```

However, when I work with the resulting PFX file in something like certutil, it doesn't ask for a private key password.  For example here is an example of what I get when i dump the cert with certutil:

```
> certutil -dump cert.pfx
Certificates: Not Encrypted
================ Certificate 0 ================

[cert data removed]

----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
  Key Container = PfxContainer
  Provider = PfxProvider
Encryption test FAILED
CertUtil: -dump command completed successfully.
```

If I use the certificates MMC snapin to export the cert I can select the "Enable  certificate privacy" option and it will export an encrypted certificate.

My question is...

Is there a way to tell the export-pfxcertificate cmdlet to enable certificate privacy so that it is encypted? If not, what other solution do I have?

Comment: What is `$privateKeyPass`? `Export-PfxCertificate` expects a `SecureString`

Comment: It is a securestring

Comment: Something like that 
$privateKeyPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "YourPassword" -Force -AsPlainText